# Is there a way of writing txt columns to a csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

So I have 8 different .txt files that I want to take 1 data column from and create a csv file of all those data columns. I used this to get the column I want:

```
china_data = pd.read_csv('China results.txt', header=None, usecols=[0], sep='\t')
```

But I can't find anywhere that explains how to add these columns of data to a singular csv folder.

I've seen the

```
f.open("filename", "w")
```

But not sure if I can use that for what I'm trying to do.

Edit: the files I'm merging have this format,

```
             0
0      1.0
1      1.0
2      1.0
3      1.0
4      1.0
...    ...
14897  1.0
14898  1.0
14899  1.0
14900  1.0
14901  1.0

[14902 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: you need to merge all the columns into a csv file? What do the lines in .txt files look like?

Comment: I've edited the document. I'm only merging the first column which I've separated using the  pd.read_cvs command.

Comment: Is there a `tab` between columns or a `space`? is the `0` in first line on purpose there?

Comment: you have a dataframe stored in `china_data`, you can extract first column with `first_col = china_data.columns[0]`, now you make an empty array with `new_csv_lines = []` and after that you append those columns to array, `new_csv_lines.append(first_col)` and then write this array mix of 7 columns into a csv file using delimeters you prefer. If you use a `,`as  a delimeter, your values need to be separated by `,`

Comment: The zero just denotes the column the 1.0 is the first line of the list. and a space between each column but I have extracted only the zeroth column of each txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood, you need to read `txt` files and write the first column to a `csv` file. For your usecase, I wrote functions to read csv, extract first column, combine all of first columns of your data and write them to a `csv` file at the end. For that you need to specify filenames of your data files.

```
def read_csv(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return lines[1:len(lines)-1] #ignoring your first line and last line

def extract_first_column(file_path): #returns first column
    lines = read_csv(file_path)
    first_col = []
    for elem in lines:
        elem = elem.strip().split(" ")
        if not elem == "":
            first_col.append(elem[0])
    return first_col

def combined_array(file_path_list): #combines all of columns to one array
    all_values = []
    for file_path in file_path_list:
        col_data = extract_first_column(file_path)
        all_values.append(col_data)
    return all_values

def write_csv(array, csv_name, delim):  #writes the array to a csv file
    with open(csv_name,"w") as f:
        for elem in array:
            if not elem == "":
                f.write(elem + delim)

file_name_list = ["data.txt"]   #you specify all 7 filenames here
array = combined_array(file_name_list)   #array containing all 7 columns
array = [x for sublist in array for x in sublist]
write_csv(array, "test.csv", "\n") #writing to csv file
```

This worked for me with the sample file you provided. I will update my answer if I misunderstood your request.

Comment: Hi, I tried running this but it only returned the first file in full instead of the first columns of all the files combined.

Comment: I just updated the answer! I forgot to remove some debug parameters. @RhysJones